# React Query useQuery cannot read property data of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my code in codepan: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-drake-4juxg?file=/src/Persons/persons.jsx

I don't have any idea why it is throwing an error that cannot read property data of undefined when sometimes it is reading it!

I have created a json file in my public folder:

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "address": "Main Street",
    "gender": "male",
    "country": "USA",
    "city": "LA"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Michael",
    "lastName": "Zeburgee",
    "address": "Second Street",
    "gender": "male",
    "country": "Germany",
    "city": "Hamburg"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Julia",
    "lastName": "Hleb",
    "address": "St.Patric",
    "gender": "female",
    "country": "Belarus",
    "city": "Minsk"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Petar",
    "lastName": "Pan",
    "address": "Some Street",
    "gender": "male",
    "country": "UK",
    "city": "London"
  }
]
```

I have an axios request:

```
import axios from "axios";

export default async function getPersonsInfo() {
  const response = await axios.get("persons.json");
  return response;
}
```

There is a Persons component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import getPersonsInfo from "../api/personCalls";

export default function Persons() {
  const [persons, setPersons] = useState([]);
  const { data: personsData, status } = useQuery(
    "personsData",
    getPersonsInfo,
    {
      onSuccess: () => {
        setPersons(personsData.data);
      },
      onError: (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  );

  return (
    <>
      {status === "loading" ? (
        <div>Loading ... </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          {persons.map((person) => (
            <div>
              <p>{person.name}</p>
              <p>{person.lastName}</p>
              <p>{person.address}</p>
              <p>{person.gender}</p>
              <p>{person.country}</p>
              <p>{person.city}</p>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

The problem is that it cannot read the data, but if I console.log(personsData) there is data.

```
onSuccess: () => {
        setPersons(personsData.data);
      },
```

You can see in the codepan. First when you open the file it is Loading... and fetching the data, but once you refresh the page it cannot!

Comment: you don't need a state, `useQuery` already manages the state. Just use `data: personData` directly.

Comment: Could you update the code, because something is wrong again, there is an error that personsData.map is not a function.

Comment: The `data` is not an array before the query is complete, so you have to provide some kind of default state that takes this into account, like `(data || []).map(/* ... */)`

Comment: So why am I using this ternary operator {status === "loading" ? <div>Loading ...</div> : (/* ... */), if it is executing it even if it's not complete!? And again I could not run it properly, even I could not get the idea. Do you mean (peronData || []).map ? cause there is an error again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the data from the onSuccess callback:

```
onSuccess: (data) => {
        console.log('data',data)
```

See the data logged, then use setPersons to set data you need to the state.

Comment: Could you update my code in codepan, because it is throwing an error that personsData.map is not a function ....